# Remove Section numbers from the items in the reference list in book

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, books

I would like to remove from the reference items the numbers that indicate where the item is cited in the book. To be clear, I have highlighted them in the screenshot.

I'm using the documentclass book and natbib. In the following the list of the relevant latex commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{book}
[...]
\usepackage{natbib}
[...]
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
```

[image: I'd like to remove these Section numbers]

Comment: Is the option `backref=false` of the package `hyperref` set? If it is not, use it.

Comment: @PietroD'Antuono You are right indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The package hyperref is responsible for adding the section numbers (or page numbers) to the bibliography. The command is indeed `backref` or `pagebackref`.

Source: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks